# bluetooth connectivity issue with external device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to an external hardware device called a slate with my code. I follow the instructions in their API guideline to have the device work with my android app. But, there seems to be something beyond my notice here that I can't even find info about in their example app.... The jist is: I try connecting to the device but the connection isn't made. Here's the debug output from before I click on the Connect to until after I click Connect...

```
06-07 02:44:06.384 4444-4444/com.example.qwill.thoughtcast I/BluetoothDevice: connectGatt
06-07 02:44:06.386 1553-2143/? W/Bth: BluetoothFreeze:tag: 181  uid: 10143  pid: 4444
06-07 02:44:06.387 1873-2001/? I/BluetoothState: new active bluetooth uid: 10143, pid:4444, reason:BLE_CONNECT
06-07 02:44:06.396 1553-2143/? W/Bth: BluetoothFreeze:tag: 181  uid: 10143  pid: 4444
06-07 02:44:06.396 1553-2143/? I/BtGatt.JNI: gattClientRegisterAppNative(L997): gattClientRegisterAppNative, register_client begin
    gattClientRegisterAppNative(L1003): gattClientRegisterAppNative, register_client
    gattClientRegisterAppNative(L1005): gattClientRegisterAppNative, register_client finish
06-07 02:44:06.396 1553-2048/? I/bt_att: GATT_Register
    GATT_Register: allocated gatt_if=6
    GATT_StartIf gatt_if=6
06-07 02:44:06.396 1553-1762/? W/bt_btif: HAL bt_gatt_callbacks->client->register_client_cb
```

If this makes any sense to anyone as to why I can't connect to my device, please enlighten me.

Here's where I connect to my device...

```
listie.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int  position, long id) {
                // Stop scanning
                slateManager.stopScan();
                slateManager.connect(slateManager.getDeviceByIndex(position));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To pair the device. use this code. It works for me

```
public class BTBluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList = new 
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;

    private TextView mStatusTv;
    private Button mActivateBtn;
    private Button mPairedBtn;
    private Button mScanBtn;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_btbluetooth);

            mStatusTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
            mActivateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enable);
            mPairedBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_view_paired);
            mScanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);

            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            mProgressDlg = new ProgressDialog(this);

            mProgressDlg.setMessage("Scanning...");
            mProgressDlg.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDlg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
            });

            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                showUnsupported();
            } else {
                mPairedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                        if (pairedDevices == null || pairedDevices.size() == 0) {
                            showToast("No Paired Devices Found");
                        } else {
                            ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> list = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

                            list.addAll(pairedDevices);

                            if (list != null) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(BTBluetoothActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", list);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(BTBluetoothActivity.this, "Bluetooth device not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                mScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        ensureDiscoverable();
                        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    }
                });


                mActivateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

                            showDisabled();
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                });


                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    showEnabled();
                } else {
                    showDisabled();
                }
            }

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);

            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

            IntentFilter btCheck = new IntentFilter();
            btCheck.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
            btCheck.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
            registerReceiver(btConnectionCheck, btCheck);
        }

    private void ensureDiscoverable() {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
                    BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
                Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 3000);
                startActivity(discoverableIntent);
            }
        }

    @Override
        public void onPause() {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

    @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(btConnectionCheck);
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            super.onDestroy();
        }

    private void showEnabled() {

            mStatusTv.setText("Bluetooth is On");
            mStatusTv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            mActivateBtn.setText("Turn OFF");
            mActivateBtn.setEnabled(true);

            mPairedBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mScanBtn.setEnabled(true);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mPairedBtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle));
                mScanBtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle));
            }
        }

        private void showDisabled() {
        inCheck = true;
            mStatusTv.setText("Bluetooth is Off");
            mStatusTv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            mActivateBtn.setText("Turn ON");
            mActivateBtn.setEnabled(true);

            mPairedBtn.setEnabled(false);
            mScanBtn.setEnabled(false);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mPairedBtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectcheck));
                mScanBtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectcheck));
            }
        }

        private void showUnsupported() {
            mStatusTv.setText("Bluetooth is unsupported by this device");
        inCheck = false;
            mActivateBtn.setText("Turn ON");
            mActivateBtn.setEnabled(false);

            mPairedBtn.setEnabled(false);
            mScanBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }

    private void showToast(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                    final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                    if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                        showToast("Enabled");

                        showEnabled();
                    }
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                    mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

                    mProgressDlg.show();
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                    mProgressDlg.dismiss();
                    if (inCheck) {
                        if (mDeviceList == null || mDeviceList.size() == 0) {
                            showToast("No bluetooth device found around");
                        } else {
                            Intent newIntent = new Intent(BTBluetoothActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                            newIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", mDeviceList);
                            startActivity(newIntent);
                        }

                    }
                } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    mDeviceList.add(device);

    //                showToast("Found device " + device.getName());
                }
                else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                    BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                        Log.d(DEVICE_NAME, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED.");
            // Device will be pair and return here
                    }
                    //case2: creating a bone
                    if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                        Log.d(DEVICE_NAME, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
                    }
                    //case3: breaking a bond
                    if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                        Log.d(DEVICE_NAME, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    BroadcastReceiver btConnectionCheck = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "BT Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "BT DisConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Device list class

```
public class DeviceListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mListView;
    private TextView status;
    private DeviceListAdapters mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList;
    private boolean doubleActivity;
    private BluetoothDevice device;

    private boolean stopWorker;
    private int readBufferPosition;
    private Thread workerThread;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    private byte[] readBuffer;
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

        mDeviceList     = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("device.list");

        mListView       = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_paired);

        mAdapter        = new DeviceListAdapters(this);

        status = findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
        status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        mAdapter.setData(mDeviceList);
        mAdapter.setListener(new DeviceListAdapters.OnPairButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPairButtonClick(int position) {
                device = mDeviceList.get(position);

                if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    unpairDevice(device);
                } else {
                    showToast("Pairing...");
                    pairDevice(device);
                }
            }
        });

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        registerReceiver(mPairReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mPairReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
            method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
            doubleActivity = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
            method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mPairReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                final int state         = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
                final int prevState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

                if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    showToast("Paired");
                } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                    showToast("Unpaired");
                }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (doubleActivity){
            finish();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Adapter-class

```
    public class DeviceListAdapters extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<BluetoothDevice> mData;
    private OnPairButtonClickListener mListener;

    public DeviceListAdapters(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setData(List<BluetoothDevice> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public void setListener(OnPairButtonClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return (mData == null) ? 0 : mData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView         =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_devices, null);

            holder              = new ViewHolder();

            holder.nameTv       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.addressTv    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
            holder.pairBtn      = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pair);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device  = mData.get(position);

        holder.nameTv.setText(device.getName());
        holder.addressTv.setText(device.getAddress());
        holder.pairBtn.setText((device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) ? "Unpair" : "Pair");
        holder.pairBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onPairButtonClick(position);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView nameTv;
        TextView addressTv;
        TextView pairBtn;
    }

    public interface OnPairButtonClickListener {
        public abstract void onPairButtonClick(int position);
    }

}
```

activity_btbluetooth.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green"
    tools:context="com.BTBluetooth.BTBluetoothActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_bt"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btbackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_below="@id/icon_bt"
        app:cardElevation="60dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:background="@drawable/loginrect"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/tv_status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="#ff0000"
                android:text="Bluetooth off" />

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/btn_enable"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Turn On" />

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/btn_view_paired"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="view paired" />

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/btn_scan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="scan devices" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_device_list.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bebebe"
    tools:context="com..BTBluetooth.DeviceListActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/toolbarcolor"
        android:text="Bluetooth Devices" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_paired"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_devices.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="#e1e1e1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/switch_track_on"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="text pair" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Galaxy Nexus" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:text="000000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thank you! Problem persists however. My issue is the device connects sometimes, while others, it appears to be doing nothing. The second one happens more frequently.

Comment: try this API in this link will help u in different ways. https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary . u have to create a library in your project and add all the java & xml files in your library then follow the steps. simple method calls will help you in device pairing, socket establish and receive data is done through the override methods.

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen in many BLE apps, they keep some time between the `stopScan()` and `connecGatt()` methods.

1. Scanning and Selection, i.e. `startScan()` and `stopScan()`
2. Connecting, i.e. `connectGatt()`
3. Performing tasks, like `transferData()`

> Keeping some time between these tasks definitely helps in efficiency
>   of LE connections.